Nginx Ingress Redirect Issue
I've deployed my path based ingress on /test path , when I'm trying to access the application using the /test path it's hitting the page.
We can see the loading icon but the css and js files are trying to fetch from / path instead of /test path
And this issue I'm facing for many frontend and backend applications
Here is my ingress file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: Ingress

metadata:

 name: test-frontend-ingress

 namespace: test

 annotations:

    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

    nginx.org/server-snippet:  "proxy_ssl_verify off;"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

            add_header X-Content-Type-Options off;     

            more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;"

            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";       

            add_header Pragma "no-cache";       

            add_header X-Frame-Options "deny";       

            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

spec:

 ingressClassName: nginx

 rules:

 - http:

     paths:

     - path: /test(/|$)(.*)

       pathType: ImplementationSpecific

       backend:

         service:

           name: test-frontend-service

           port:

            number: 80


Have you checked this issue. Can you please add an ingress yaml file.

can you share the full ingress rule ?

@PranayKumarKyasala yes I'm following that approach only but still facing same issue

are you sure this is nginx issue ?, your UI web server code might be hardcoded to use "/" instead of the prefix "/test"

You need to be careful around closing your quotes accordingly and for multiline use |
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite_target: /$2
   nginx.org/server-snippet: "proxy_ssl_verify off;"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          add_header x-Content- Type-Options off;
          more_set_headers "strict-Transport Security: max- age=31536000;"
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          add_header X-Frame-Options "deny";
          add_header x-Content-Type-O Options nosniff";

It is recommended that you use the custom header annotation and inject from a configmap instead of configuration-snippet for headers (as in your example code)

Thanks for the info I've updated,  it was my mistake
